# login windows auth website( host in test domain) use different account

Tags: dns, windows-authentication

I have a website which host in a private domain. It uses windows auth. I can log on the site as TestDomain\user1, TestDomain\user2.
When I used the user2 to log on the website , the browser remembered the user. I cannot use the user1 to log on the site. How can I log off user2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. click <kbd>Start</kbd> button
2. type "vault"
3. select "manage windows credentials"
4. delete the stored password